# Error handling for AWS SQS with Lambda triggers and reserved capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using the approach described [here](https://dev.to/piczmar_0/error-handling-in-aws-lambda-trigger-by-sqs-events-3amp) to move messages that were processed in error by a lambda function triggered by SQS to a DeadLetterQueue.

In my case the ReservedCapacity of the lambda function is set to a small value - I want to limit the number of concurrent executions. What happens is that, even with Cloudwatch logs/metrics not showing lambda execution errors, some messages are not processed and are sent to the DLQ.

The lambda function is being throttled, which is expected. It seems that when the function is throttled the message is removed from SQS and then returned, which causes the message to end in the DLQ even though there are no errors in the lambda execution code.

Right now I'm increasing maxReceiveCount from 1 to 3 as a workaround. Is there a better way to sent only Lambda execution errors (not including throttling) to DLQ?

```
  SearchJobsQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties:
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
      VisibilityTimeout: 60
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn:    
            "Fn::GetAtt":       
              - SearchJobsDLQ
              - Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 3
```

**EDIT**: My goal is for the DLQ to receive only lambdas with errors that were not dealt explicitly within lambda code. The workaround has the following issues: in case of **permanent errors** the message will be processed at least 3 times before ending in the DLQ when 1 time would suffice; depending on the time required to processes all the queue messages and on the interval that the queue is checked by the lambda trigger it is possible that a message not processed due to throttling 3 times ends in the DLQ.

Answer (score 1):

This AWS [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDAXRKwTQIk&feature=youtu.be&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTmpSbU4yTXhNbVV5TTJFeiIsInQiOiJJclg2eEMxSHkyXC9jbEM5cnBuSVppMDEzOWQ0Y0VBNHBWQU9xRlFvUnVuQkVNcHpobXlpejRxOWVYcmYrZkhIZTVXNUVBOFwvcVNDQ2VteUI5M0wrN3kzRUZubkZCY2lcL0xQbW1td3FBTm92aTZDc242UjZUM0ZRcDVndXhUd1J0TVJqbFdHc2FWeHZsWEJtWm8wUjlqOVE9PSJ9) covers the topic in details. Messages that are not consumed because of throttling are returned to the queue and treated the same way used for messages not consumed because of other errors during lambda execution. There are however guidelines for that cases, such as defining the queue's visibility timeout of 5-6 times the lambda timeout.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to the video, it is one of the best presentations I have seen on SQS so far and clarified a lot of things for me. Still, it feels odd to me that SQS can't do what you (and I) are asking for: "Permanent" errors (e.g. Exceptions) go straight to the DLQ while messages from throttling errors go back to the queue to be retried. Of course, you can fiddle with the timeouts but I would really like to have a solution out of the box...